# How to keep the order of the xml elements while transform using xslt2.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

**This is XML Document.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">

  <w:body>
    <w:p>
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/>
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Tables</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>

    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Table1</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>

    <w:tbl>
      <w:tr>
        <w:tc>
          <w:p>
            <w:r>
              <w:t>row1col1</w:t>
            </w:r>
          </w:p>
        </w:tc>
        <w:tc>
          <w:p>
            <w:r>
              <w:t>row1col2</w:t>
            </w:r>
          </w:p>
        </w:tc>
      </w:tr>

      <w:tr>
        <w:tc>
          <w:p>
            <w:r>
              <w:t>row2col1</w:t>
            </w:r>
          </w:p>
        </w:tc>

        <w:tc>
          <w:p>
            <w:r>
              <w:t>row2col2</w:t>
            </w:r>
          </w:p>
        </w:tc>
      </w:tr>
    </w:tbl>

    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Table2</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>

    <w:tbl>
      <w:tr>
        <w:tc>
          <w:p>
            <w:r>
              <w:t>row11col11</w:t>
            </w:r>
          </w:p>
        </w:tc>

        <w:tc>
          <w:p>
            <w:r>
              <w:t>row11col12</w:t>
            </w:r>
          </w:p>
        </w:tc>
      </w:tr>

      <w:tr>
        <w:tc>
          <w:p>
            <w:r>
              <w:t>row12col11</w:t>
            </w:r>
          </w:p>
        </w:tc>

        <w:tc>
          <w:p>
            <w:r>
              <w:t>row12col12</w:t>
            </w:r>
          </w:p>
        </w:tc>
      </w:tr>
    </w:tbl>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

**and i want to transform this xml document into below mentioned format using my xslt file.**

```
<Document>
<Heading1>
<title>Tables</title>
<paragraph>Table1</paragraph>
<table>
   <paragraph>row1col1</paragraph>
   <paragraph>row1col2</paragraph>
   <paragraph>row2col1</paragraph>
   <paragraph>row2col2</paragraph>
</table>
<paragraph>Table2</paragraph>
<table>
   <paragraph>row11col11</paragraph>
   <paragraph>row11col12</paragraph>
   <paragraph>row12col11</paragraph>
   <paragraph>row12col12</paragraph>
</table>
</Heading1>
</Document>
```

**This is my XSLT File for your reference...**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
                              xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">

    <Document>

      <xsl:variable name="headingName" select="(//w:body/w:p/w:pPr/w:pStyle[starts-with(@w:val, 'Heading')])[1]/@w:val"/>
      <xsl:variable name="topLevelHeadings" select = "//w:body/w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val = $headingName]"/>

      <xsl:choose>

        <xsl:when test="$topLevelHeadings">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$topLevelHeadings">
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="//w:p[w:r[w:t]]">
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </Document>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="w:p">
    <Paragraph>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="./w:r/w:t"/>
    </Paragraph>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::w:p">
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="w:t">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>



  <xsl:template match="//w:body/w:p[w:pPr[w:pStyle[starts-with(@w:val,'Heading')]]]">

    <Heading1>
      <Title>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./w:r/w:t"/>
      </Title>

      <xsl:choose>

        <xsl:when test="following-sibling::w:tbl//w:p[w:r[w:t]]">
          <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::w:tbl">

            <table>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::w:p ">
              </xsl:apply-templates>
            </table>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::w:p">
            <!-- | following-sibling::w:tbl//w:p[w:r[w:t]]-->
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:otherwise>

      </xsl:choose>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::w:p[w:r and not(w:pPr[w:pStyle])] | following-sibling::w:p[w:r and not(w:pPr[w:pStyle[starts-with(@w:val,'Heading')]])]">
      </xsl:apply-templates>

      <xsl:variable name="nextHead" select="concat('Heading', number(substring-after('Heading1', 'Heading'))+1)"/>

      <!-- Get a list of child nodes (headings) for the current node -->
      <xsl:variable name="nextLevelHeadings" select="following-sibling::w:p[w:pPr[w:pStyle[@w:val=$nextHead]]]"/>

      <!-- Apply recursively for next level headings within the scope -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$nextLevelHeadings">
      </xsl:apply-templates>

      <!-- Close heading tag -->
    </Heading1>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**But the output is :**

```
<Document>
<Heading1>
 <Title>Table Manipulation</Title>
  <table>
       <paragraph>row1col1</paragraph>
       <paragraph>row1col2</paragraph>
       <paragraph>row2col1</paragraph>
       <paragraph>row2col2</paragraph>
  </table>
  <table>
       <paragraph>row11col11</paragraph>
       <paragraph>row11col12</paragraph>
       <paragraph>row12col11</paragraph>
       <paragraph>row12col12</paragraph>
 </table>
  <Paragraph>Table1</Paragraph>
  <Paragraph>Table2</Paragraph>
  </Heading1>
</Document>
```

So, Please Guide me to get this issue and it will be work like my above said output requirement.Because, i want to transform this xml file without changing order of the paragraphs or tables.

Thanks & Regards,
p.saravanan

Comment: I've tried the stylesheet on your provided XML (after fixing the namespace for prefix `w`) but am getting a different result than the output you've shown at the end of your post. Are you sure this is what you're getting with the XML and XSLT you've provided?

Comment: @G_H: yes, it produced my same output that i mentioned in my end of my post.

Comment: @Saravanan I copied both your .xml and your .xslt and run the transform. I don't get the output you are claiming to have.

Comment: @G_H: I have modified my input xml document for your clear reference. Please refer it.

Comment: @FailedDev:I have modified my input xml document for your clear reference. Please refer it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have completed that task and thank you all for your co-operation in this...

i just attached modified xslt file that is working absolutley fine...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
                              xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">

    <Document>

      <xsl:variable name="headingName" select="(//w:body/w:p/w:pPr/w:pStyle[starts-with(@w:val, 'Heading')])[1]/@w:val"/>
      <xsl:variable name="topLevelHeadings" select = "//w:body/w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val = $headingName]"/>

      <xsl:choose>

        <xsl:when test="$topLevelHeadings">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$topLevelHeadings">
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="//w:p[w:r[w:t]]">
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </Document>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="w:p">
    <Paragraph>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="./w:r/w:t"/>
    </Paragraph>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::w:p">
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="w:t">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>



  <xsl:template match="//w:body/w:p[w:pPr[w:pStyle[starts-with(@w:val,'Heading')]]]">

    <Heading1>
      <Title>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./w:r/w:t"/>
      </Title>

     <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::*">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="descendant::w:p">
            <table>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::w:p ">
              </xsl:apply-templates>
            </table>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="self::w:p[w:r and not(w:pPr[w:pStyle])] | self::w:p[w:r and not(w:pPr[w:pStyle[starts-with(@w:val,'Heading')]])]">
            </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>

      <!--<xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::w:p[w:r and not(w:pPr[w:pStyle])] | following-sibling::w:p[w:r and not(w:pPr[w:pStyle[starts-with(@w:val,'Heading')]])]">
      </xsl:apply-templates>-->

      <xsl:variable name="nextHead" select="concat('Heading', number(substring-after('Heading1', 'Heading'))+1)"/>

      <!-- Get a list of child nodes (headings) for the current node -->
      <xsl:variable name="nextLevelHeadings" select="following-sibling::w:p[w:pPr[w:pStyle[@w:val=$nextHead]]]"/>

      <!-- Apply recursively for next level headings within the scope -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$nextLevelHeadings">
      </xsl:apply-templates>

      <!-- Close heading tag -->
    </Heading1>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

By indenting your code properly, it showed that you missed a `</w:p>`.

I indented it and added it here. This may or may not fix your problem.

```
<w:document xmlns:w="w">
    <w:body>
        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Tables</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>

        <w:p>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>Table1</w:t>
            </w:r>

            <w:tbl>
                <w:tr>
                    <w:tc>
                        <w:p>
                            <w:r>
                                <w:t>row1col</w:t>
                            </w:r>
                        </w:p>
                    </w:tc>
                    <w:tc>
                        <w:p>
                            <w:r>
                                <w:t>row1co2</w:t>
                            </w:r>
                        </w:p>
                    </w:tc>
                </w:tr>
                <w:tr>
                    <w:tc>
                        <w:p>
                            <w:r>
                                <w:t>row2col1</w:t>
                            </w:r>
                        </w:p>
                    </w:tc>
                    <w:tc>
                        <w:p>
                            <w:r>
                                <w:t>row2col2</w:t>
                            </w:r>
                        </w:p>
                    </w:tc>
                </w:tr>
            </w:tbl>

            <w:p>
                <w:r>
                    <w:t>Table2</w:t>
                </w:r> 
            </w:p>           

            <w:tbl>
                <w:tr>
                    <w:tc>
                        <w:p>
                            <w:r>
                                <w:t>row11col11</w:t>
                            </w:r>
                        </w:p>
                    </w:tc>
                    <w:tc>
                        <w:p>
                            <w:r>
                                <w:t>row11co12</w:t>
                            </w:r>
                        </w:p>
                    </w:tc>
                </w:tr>
                <w:tr>
                    <w:tc>
                        <w:p>
                            <w:r>
                                <w:t>row12col11</w:t>
                            </w:r>
                        </w:p>
                    </w:tc>
                    <w:tc>
                        <w:p>
                            <w:r>
                                <w:t>row12col12</w:t>
                            </w:r>
                        </w:p>
                    </w:tc>
                </w:tr>
            </w:tbl>
        </w:p>
    <w:body>
</w:document>
```

Comment: It would be better to use a comment or suggest an edit. It's not gonna solve the problem anyway, probably was a typo or the result of cutting too much out of the original document.

Comment: @Jan Dragsbaek:Thank you... I have updated my question.i just missed it here only...

Comment: @G_H: Sorry G_H . i already cut out so many unnecessary codes for easy reference.If i do so, you cann't able to understand the files.That's why i put the small length file.Please understand me...